# Override __import__ in python

Tags: python, initialization, derived-class, base-class

I need to override __import__ function in python when I dynamically import a derived class. (I only have access to the base class code). For example:

```
Servers=[]

class ServerBase(object):
    name='' #name of the specific server class, for each server class

    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False
        self.name = self.__class__.__module__.capitalize()
        Servers.append(self)
```

When a derived class is imported I need to call __init__ of the base class to add it to Servers[] list, so when in the main module I call:

```
__import__('DerivedClassName')
```

Base __init__ will be called

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just use a factory function that produces the derived class and instance?

Comment: Don't see, what this have to do with  `import`.

Comment: I don't have access to the derived class or to the main function that imports that derived class (only the base)

Comment: @AlexGill: a factory function you call to import the derived class and create an instance of it there and then would solve this better than hooking into each and every import.

Comment: @AlexGill: you can otherwise inject a new `__import__` wrapper into the main function globals, but I'd consider that a last-ditch effort. You'd be better off monkeypatching the `DerivedClassName` global in that module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is my problem: I don't have access to the main function or to the derived class. My only point of contact is the base class. Is it possible to override *\__import__* ?

Comment: @AlexGill: you can also replace the base class and give it a `__new__` method, or give it a metaclass with a `__call__` method. I already said you can override `__import__`, but that's only needed if the `from module import DerivededClass` statement is *in a function*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I guess the best way is to give `ServerBase` a metaclass. How do I implement a `__call__` method on it?

Comment: For reference, I guess the confusion between "importing a file" and "creating a class" comes from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up metaclassing the Servers class:

```
Servers=[]

''' Servers Metaclass that handles addition of servers to the list '''
class MetaServer(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        self.name = name.capitalize()
        Servers.append(self)
        super(MetaServer, self).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class ServerBase:
    __metaclass__ = MetaServer
    name='' #name of the specific server class, for each server class

    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False
```

That way every time a derived class was imported meta-init got called.
Exactly what I wanted.
Thanks @MartijnPieters